# Right syntax of SqlParameter

Tags: c#, sql, database, syntax, sqlparameter

I'm trying to convert :

```
command.Parameters.Add (new SqliteParameter (DbType.Int32) { Value = id });
```

To a normal SqlParameter :

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(DbType.Int32) { Value = id });
```

I've managed to convert every line now besides this one, I'm getting these errors :

```
Error   3   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.DbType' to 'object[]'
Error   2   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.SqlParameter(object[])' has some invalid arguments
```

Full function code :

```
public User GetUser(int id)
{
    var u = new User();
    lock (locker)
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + path + ";Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=sa;Password=***********th");
        connection.Open();
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "Select * from tblUsers WHERE UserID = ?";
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(DbType.Int32) { Value = id });
            var r = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (r.Read())
            {
                u = FromReader(r);
                break;
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    return u;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking something this;

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@YourParameterName", SqlDbType.Int32).Value = id;
```

After edit your question;

You can use [`AddWithValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. [`Add(String, Object)` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is obsolete. like;

```
command.CommandText = "Select * from tblUsers WHERE UserID = @id";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

If you use SQL Server as a database, you should named your parameter add it to `AddWithValue` with the same name.

When you use [`OleDbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), order of parameter is important. Because as [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) says:

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?
```

> Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Comment: How am I supposed to know what to insert in `@YourParameterName` ? The SqliteParameter function is pretty straight forward.

Comment: @Random This is a parameter name where you put your sql command. Show your sql command also to figure out what is your problem exactly.

Comment: Code is too long for a comment and I can't answer my own question because I have less than 10 reputation

Comment: @Random Just put your relevant command part. You can always edit your question with `edit` button in under your question.

Comment: Added it in the question. Also, another question, why is the `WHERE UserID = ?`, the question mark I mean.

Comment: So I should just disregard the `command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(DbType.Int32) { Value = id });` And replace it with `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);` ?

Comment: @Random Yes, `Add` method is obsolete now. You should use `AddWithValue` instead. Also don't forget to change `UserID = ?` to `UserID = @id`.

Comment: Just a note for clarification: Only Add(String, Object) is obsolete. Add(String, SqlDbType), Add(String, SqlDbType, Int32), etc. are still legit and, in some circumstances, are better to use instead of AddWithValue(String, Object). (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)